# Get LngLat form XY

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I need to get lngLat coordinates from Mapbox map container center once the map is loaded and during user interaction with it. Tried to do on the basis of [Get coordinates of the mouse pointer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/) example but can't realize how to change e.point JSON coordinates from dynamic mouse cursor XY-coordinates to static XY-coordinates of map viewport center (outerWidht/2 and outerHeight/2).

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox.js and MapboxGL both offer `getCenter` methods that return a map view's geographic center.

You can use various events such as `moveend` to update the center dynamically.